# How we can create Android Chrome web applications that are present on the Google Chrome web store

Tags: android, google-chrome

Im new to Android and Google chrome web application development. I want to create an android application which has the ability to run Chrome web applications that are present on the Google Chrome web store. Can some body guide me , how I can start and where can i find the step by step helping documents. I googled it , but dint get any .

If any sample codes available to start, then that would be really helpful.

thanks and regards
Suje

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two kinds of Chrome Web Store (CWS) apps: packaged and hosted. Packaged ones don't have a URL and can only run inside Chrome. Hosted apps are just regular web applications hosted at a URL and can in theory run from any browser, provided that it supports the features needed by the app.

There are a few ways to embed web apps into an Android application, the most popular of which is PhoneGap. Here's a nice getting started guide. http://www.phonegap.com/start/